# Warning, using: typearea, a5, BCOR=8mm, DIV=calc

Tags: koma-script, typearea

can you please help me to avoid the warning that arises by using:

```
twoside=true, fontsize=10pt, BCOR=8mm, \recalctypearea
```

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}   % für angepasste Kopf-/Fußzeilen
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=0.2ex}

\KOMAoptions{twoside=true}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}
\KOMAoptions{paper=A5}
\KOMAoptions{headinclude=true}
\KOMAoptions{footinclude=false}
\KOMAoptions{mpinclude=false}

\KOMAoptions{BCOR=8mm}
%\KOMAoptions{DIV=18}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Doing so, why do I need to set

```
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}
```

before the other \KOMAoptions to avoid a warning.

Comment: You could try the silence package. Or simply learn to ignore the message (the KOMA classes like to warn about a lot of things)

Answer (score 5):

If you include the option `pagesize`, everything gets calculated correctly. No need for `\recalctypearea` here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[%
    ,twoside=true
    ,fontsize=10pt
    ,paper=a5
    ,pagesize % this was missing.
    ,BCOR=8mm
    ,headinclude=true
    ,footinclude=false
    ,mpinclude=false
    ,headsepline=0.2ex
    ,DIV=calc
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}   % für angepasste Kopf-/Fußzeilen
\usepackage{blindtext}
\recalctypearea % not needed here, but in order to show that it is working without warnings.

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works for me. That leads to correct page layout without hyperref, too.

Comment: Option `pagesize` is default since KOMA-Script v3.17.

Comment: Your solution is more to move the options to `\documentclass` instead of setting them by single `\KOMAoptions` commands.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the warning change the order of `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=8mm}` and `\KOMAoptions{DIV=18}` or use `\typearea[8mm]{18}` to set `BCOR` and `DIV` at the same time.

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{scrreprt}% -> default: paper=a4, fontsize=11pt -> DIV=10

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=0.2ex}

\KOMAoptions{twoside=true}% -> recalculation of the page layout
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}
\KOMAoptions{paper=A5}
\KOMAoptions{headinclude=true}
\KOMAoptions{footinclude=false}
\KOMAoptions{mpinclude=false}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=18}% -> recalculation of the page layout
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=8mm}% -> recalculation of the page layout

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

If you use `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=8mm}` before you set the `DIV` value to `18` (or `calc`) the `DIV` value used in the recalculation of the page layout is too low for  `paper=A5`. So you get a warning.

Comment: I did not know that the order of these commands is important. Thanks for the additional explenation.